# jquery div & radiobutton viewstate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 divs which I show or hide depending on a button click event.
I use the `.hide()` and `.show()` jquery methods.

One of the divs has two radiobuttons.
when this particular div is hidden and then shown the radiobutton selection is lost.

Can someone help please.

Comment: Sounds odd.  Can you provide a fiddle that reproduces this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce this problem. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qAs9x/3/ - the value of radio group stays the same after hide/show.